# Can we access the SP hosted App's URL in SP designer workflow 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, designer-workflow

Here I wants to add some links in mails which will redirect user to SP app,so for this I want to access SP App's URL in mail body and this mail body am creating in designer workflow-2010, so is it possible to get SP apps URl in Workflow?